# Ceiling / Wall mounted heaters recomendations?

Tags: heating

My mom wants to get my step-dad a heater for his workshop in the garage, but there's very little floor space available that isn't taken up with tools, and she noticed that there's an electical plug up high on one of the walls (the ceiling's probably about 10 to 12' high).

I can find lots of wall-mounted heaters online, but I have no idea what features / etc, I should look for, or even what size I should get.

They're in southern Maryland, and they're in a bit of a valley, so it tends to be colder than normal for the area (less sunlight hits 'em); it's a two-car garage, high ceilings, and the walls are drywall, but I've never checked if they're insulated or not.  (I'm guessing not, or at least, they lose enough through the garage doors that it should be treated as if it's not)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search shows me most ceiling-mounted shop heaters are probably all 240V, so unless that plug also is, you'll need to run new electrical. I had a heater that looked something like the one below at a place I used to work, and it worked decently well.

[image]

Here's a nice [heater sizing chart](http://www.houseneeds.com/shop/HeatingProducts/heatingunits/electrical/electricindexsizingpage.asp?stype=electrical/qmark/qmarkmwuhbuypage.asp&level=1) to help decide how powerful a heater you need.